# Were power cards ever released for the Martial Power 2 book?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-sheets

I've looked online, on Amazon. Did Dungeons and Dragons create power cards for the *Martial Power 2* book? I know they did for the first *Martial Power* they came out with. I've seen cards for classes from that book. But not book 2. Anyone know? I guess if I can't find it, it's probably a no.

Answer (score 2):

### Sadly, no.

According to [this list](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?332807-4th-Edition-D-amp-D-Collector-s-Guide) of products maintained by an ENWorld user, Power Cards stopped being printed after the Divine Power set came out in early 2010.

The character builder, if you have access, should be able to get all your powers printed in that kind of layout, while also automatically including errata and anything you found in Dragon. Which is probably why they stopped with power cards, come to think of it.